# Configure vaadin-maven-plugin proxy

Tags: java, spring, maven, vaadin

I try to use **vaadin-maven-plugin** to make a package jar behind a pxoxy.
Maven adjusted use proxy from settings.xml. But when i run package goal a have a next messages:

**[INFO] No proxies configured**

**[INFO] No proxy was configured, downloading directly**

Full log:

```
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:11.0.0:package-for-production (default) @ front ---
[WARNING] The translated URL 'frontend://bower_components/vaadin-upload/theme/lumo/vaadin-upload-file.html' has no corresponding file on the filesystem, the file is addressed by path='/home/k/Documents/Projects/front/target/frontend/bower_components/vaadin-upload/theme/lumo/vaadin-upload-file.html'
[INFO] Installing required frontend tools to '/home/k/Documents/Projects/front/target'
[INFO] Installing node version v8.11.1
[INFO] Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.1/node-v8.11.1-linux-x64.tar.gz to /home/k/Documents/Projects/front/target/cache/node-v8.11.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
[INFO] No proxies configured
[INFO] No proxy was configured, downloading directly
[INFO] Unpacking /home/k/Documents/Projects/front/target/cache/node-v8.11.1-linux-x64.tar.gz into /home/k/Documents/Projects/front/target/node/tmp
[INFO] Copying node binary from /home/k/Documents/Projects/front/target/node/tmp/node-v8.11.1-linux-x64/bin/node to /home/k/Documents/Projects/front/target/node/node
[INFO] Installed node locally.
[INFO] Installing Yarn version v1.6.0
[INFO] Downloading https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v1.6.0/yarn-v1.6.0.tar.gz to /home/k/Documents/Projects/front/target/cache/yarn-v1.6.0.tar.gz
[INFO] No proxies configured
[INFO] No proxy was configured, downloading directly
окт 02, 2018 6:05:31 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: has_recent_activity=1; path=/; expires=Tue, 02 Oct 2018 12:05:31 -0000". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Tue, 02 Oct 2018 12:05:31 -0000
окт 02, 2018 6:05:31 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: _octo=GH1.1.1985639979.1538478331; domain=.github.com; path=/; expires=Fri, 02 Oct 2020 11:05:31 -0000". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Fri, 02 Oct 2020 11:05:31 -0000
окт 02, 2018 6:05:31 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: logged_in=no; domain=.github.com; path=/; expires=Sat, 02 Oct 2038 11:05:31 -0000; secure; HttpOnly". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Sat, 02 Oct 2038 11:05:31 -0000
[INFO] Unpacking /home/k/Documents/Projects/front/target/cache/yarn-v1.6.0.tar.gz into /home/k/Documents/Projects/front/target/node/yarn
[INFO] Installed Yarn locally.
[INFO] Running 'yarn install' in /home/k/Documents/Projects/front/target
[INFO] yarn install v1.6.0
[INFO] [1/4] Resolving packages...
```

And error in result. How to configure plugin to work with proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be from a NPM install since I see NodeJS in the logs.

Try to add a `.npmrc` file in the directory `C:\Users\<Your User>`

And add a line like

```
proxy=http://my_proxy:port
```